# How to call methods properly from a razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So basically I want to know how to call methods or right a code in the razor files

I've seen some ways over the internet that includes static classes, but I think it's not the best way to do that.

I got this code in the cshtml file:

```cs
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
</td>
```

that displays all the rows from "News" class ( in the Model )

And I want to display only the first 50 letters of the description and 3 dots afterwards, my question is where should I write this method? in the "News" class? or in another external class? and how can I access it in the razor file?

Comment: it is generally more accepted to not do any transformation in the view, but to do that in the controller action method (for instance) and save the result in the view model. This can then be passed on to the view which only needs to render it.

Comment: @ath thanks a lot for the answer! 
but it can be done for a foreach that go through all item.Description ?

Comment: To be clear, in the example we only see one model (with the description property), right? By the comment just now it seems like you want to loop over a `collection` (multiple descriptions) and render them in one view, is that correct?

Comment: @ath Yes that's the full code: foreach (var item in Model) { ... }
and in the 3 dots I use the  Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated To reflect @mjwills suggestions*

You could define(write) the method as a member method of your News Model class

```
public class NewsModel
{
    //all your properties here
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionWithDots { get { return DoTheDots(Description); } }

    //the method that writes the dots
    public string DoTheDots(string input)
    {
        return input + "some dots ...";
    }
}
```

Then in the view to call it just **don't** use the Displayfor() and call it like this:

```
 <td>
    @item(item.DescriptionWithDots)
 </td>
```

As @ath said above this is not great practice (as you are now coupling the view to the model and skipping the controller), you want to avoid calling methods in the view.
Instead you could refactor it into your Controller:

```
foreach (var item in models)
        {
            item.Description = item.DoTheDots(item.Description);
        }
        return View(models);
```

Comment: Consider making `DescriptionWithDots` as a readonly property, then use `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescriptionWithDots)`. This keeps all of the complexity in the model, not the view.

Comment: Thanks! it really helped

Comment: @mjwills Nice! Did you mean use a constructor to call the method and store the result in the read-only property?

Comment: @mjwills Thanks mate, that is a much cleaner solution.  I updated the answer